# Computing milliseconds since 1970 in C# yields different date than JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, datetime-format

I need to compute the JavaScript [getTime](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) method in C#.

For simplicity, I chose a fixed date in UTC and compared the C#:

```
C#
DateTime e = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime s = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
TimeSpan t = (e - s);
var x = t.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
=> 1325289600000
```

and the JavaScript results:

```
JavaScript
var d = new Date(2011, 12, 31, 0, 0, 0)
var utcDate = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds());
utcDate.getTime()
=> 1327960800000
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need UTC time to calculate the number of seconds between two dates? It doesn't matter what time zone, the answer is the same in any time zone.

Comment: Because in C# I'm reading the date from a DB which has stores dates in UTC.

Comment: When I execute your js code I get - 1328004000000 - http://jsfiddle.net/k5Z7h/1/

Comment: @EkoostikMartin The answer wouldn't be the same in any time zone, since time zones change over time and especially did in the last 40 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant for the input to be at UTC, you should be doing this instead:

```
var ts = Date.UTC(2011,11,31,0,0,0);
```

As SLaks pointed out, months run 0-11, but even then - you must initialize the date as UTC if you want the response in UTC.  In your code, you were initializing a *local* date, and then *converting* it to UTC.  The result would be different depending on the time zone of the computer where the code is running.   With `Date.UTC`, you get back a timestamp - not a `Date` object, and it will be the same result regardless of where it runs.

From Chrome's debugging console:

[image: Debug Output]

This is the same value returned from your .NET code, which looks just fine, except I would return a `long`, not a `string`.

Answer (score 10):

Javascript months are zero-based.
`12` means January of next year.

You want `11`.

Comment: right! to check, just type in console `new Date(1327960800000)`. result: `Mon Jan 30 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0200 (Local Daylight Time)`

Answer (score 0):

The date JS is wrong I believe. Omit the `var utcDate` line and output just `d.getTime()`

The time between two dates is the same, regardless of timezone and offset. Timezones are relative to an ACTUAL point in time, so whether you call `.getTime()` on the UTC or EST or PST date, it will be the same relative to 1970-1-1 of the same timezone.

```
2011-12-31 EST - 1970-1-1 EST 
    == 2011-12-31 PST - 1970-1-1 PST 
    == 2011-12-31 UTC - 1970-1-1 UTC
```

**EDIT:** Per @Slaks above, you also are not using the 0-based month (which I also had no idea about).